The ES256 algorithm is not allowed or supported by the JWS signer: Supported algorithms: [ES384]
The following error occurs when calling the endpoint http://localhost:8081/restClientJwt: "The ES256 algorithm is not allowed or supported by the JWS signer: Supported algorithms: [ES384]"
O.S.: "Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
Java:
"openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)"
Javac:
"openjdk version "21.0.3" 2024-04-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-21.0.3.9.1 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)"
Maven dependencies: spring-security-oauth2-jose version 6.3.1, nimbus-jose-jwt version 9.40.
Code repository: https://github.com/cassiusvm/spring-security-oauth2-restclient-interceptor
Docker Image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.4.

I solved the issue:
    private static KeyPair generateEcKey() {
    Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
    BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", bouncyCastleProvider.getName());
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
    return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
}


Indeed, it doesn't need BouncyCastle Provider, just: keyPairGenerator.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
